# Assigning a parameter to the GPU sets is_leaf as false

Tags: pytorch, cuda, gpu, autograd

If I create a `Parameter` in PyTorch, then it is automatically assigned as a leaf variable:

```py
x = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([0.1]))
print(x.is_leaf)
```

This prints out `True`. From what I understand, if `x` is a leaf variable, then it will be updated by the optimiser.

But if I then assign `x` to the GPU:

```py
x = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([0.1]))
x = x.cuda()
print(x.is_leaf)
```

This prints out `False`. So now I cannot assign `x` to the GPU and keep it as a leaf node.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is in [`is_leaf`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.Tensor.is_leaf) documentation and here is your exact case:

```
>>> b = torch.rand(10, requires_grad=True).cuda()
>>> b.is_leaf
False
# b was created by the operation that cast a cpu Tensor into a cuda Tensor
```

Citing documentation further:

> For Tensors that have `requires_grad` which is True, they will be leaf
>   Tensors if they were created by the user. This means that they are not
>   the result of an operation and so grad_fn is None.

In your case, `Tensor` **was not** created by you, but was created by PyTorch's `cuda()` operation (leaf is the pre-cuda `b`).

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix the example is to move the `.cuda()` inside the Parameter constructor:

```
torch.nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([0.1]).cuda())
print(x.is_leaf)
```

Prints out `True`.